# Hide bootstrap panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have boostarp template:

http://usman.it/themes/charisma/

I want to when user load a page the introduction panel will be hide (the same as after click on arrow) and after click on arrow the panel will be show.

I used

```
$('.collapse').collapse('toggle')
```

but it doesn't work. When I use this function to another class the arrow don't change the direction like after click on the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to remove the " **in** " class from the panel first then you need to add class " **collapsed** " there And 
when you want to show that panel you just need to use **.addClass('in');** and **.removeClass('collepsed');** 
this may work for you.